# string.join to List<string>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-to-vb.net

I want to return a List from the following code:

```
private List<string> tokenizer(string x)
.........
 ..........
i has done thank you
```

I tried to use

```
.ToList();
```

but it didn't work. can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: String.Join returns a string. What are you trying to do? If you simply want a list, just remove the string.join and replace .ToArrray with .ToList

Comment: `string.Join` creates a _single_ string.

Comment: What is the return type of the method that this is in?

Comment: A list of what?  String.Join concats a list of strings into a single string, you want to not do that?

Comment: i want return the string after remove the noisy text into List<string>

Comment: "i want return the string after remove the noisy text into List<string>" I understand each of those words *individually*.

Comment: @ aquinas, i did. but a err show that cannot convert type string.generic  to list<string.>

Comment: Presumeably he wants to get rid of some text, then put the 'cleaned' string into a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take a shot at this. Is this what your after?

```
var list = from s in Regex.Split(sb.ToString(), "([ \\t{}()\n])") 
             where s.Length > 3 && !exclude.IsMatch(s) 
             select s.Replace("!‌", "@")).ToList()
```

Then you can return it:

```
return list;
```

If this isn't what you are trying to do please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
return new List<String>(
    from s in Regex.Split(sb.ToString(), "([ \\t{}()\n])")
    where s.Length > 3 && !exclude.IsMatch(s)
    select s.Replace("!‌", "@"));
```

Not sure why you're joining the strings together if you want the list of cleaned up text.

Comment: I see you now include a method signature, what is it that my or @BaliC 's answer that isn't working for you?